# SoapRequest to NSString on iOS?

Tags: ios, objective-c, web-services, soap, sudzc

I'm using an API generated by Sudzc.com from a WDSL. I have this method:

```
- (SoapRequest*) getToolListAsXML: (id <SoapDelegate>) handler getEmptyFC: (BOOL) getEmptyFC repoid: (NSString* ) repoid
```

And I thought that It calls the webservice and receive an XML as string as the documentation generated by sudzc.com told me:

[image: documentation]

But I really don't know how the SoapDelegate works, if I want the response (the list as string) what I'm supposed to do? The examples are more confusing, it says:

[image: examples]

But, obviously,

```
NSString resp = [service getToolListAsXML:self action:@selector(getToolListAsXMLHandler:) getEmptyFC: NO repoid: @""];
```

doesn't work because of 'incompatible pointer types..."

I'm very new on this so sorry if what I'm saying has nonsense.
Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this

```
    [service getToolListAsXML:self action:@selector(getToolListAsXMLHandler:) getEmptyFC: NO repoid: @""]
    - (void) getToolListAsXMLHandler: (id) value {

if([value isKindOfClass:[NSError class]]) {
        //NSLog(@"%@", value);
        return;
    }

    // Handle faults
    if([value isKindOfClass:[SoapFault class]]) {
        //NSLog(@"%@", value);
        return;
    }
    NSString * resp =(NSString *)value;
    }
```

you will get soap request in string

Comment: Finally works, there was a problem in the API I was using. Thanks.